# Autocompletion for JQuery Javascript not working in JSP's in Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jsp

I have a JSP Page and would like to have autocomplition in my Eclipse Editor.
But it doesn't work.

- I have installed the JSDT Plugin for jQuery

[image]

- I have added the js as a Library

[image]

I am referencing the javascript in my JSP-Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/context/js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
```

But I don't have autocomplition when coding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    $( document ).ready(function() {



        $( "a" ).<HERE I PRESS CTRL-SPACE, BUT NOTHINGN HAPPENS>
    });
};
</script>
```

Any help ?

Comment: AutoComplete is a function of `jQuery UI` include that.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing, but I have added now the jquery-ui-core-6.2.2.jar via Maven (pom.xml) . After restarting Eclipse, I am still not able to autocomplete my jquery syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java)

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started) which gives you a [support for jQuery](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support) and if you need advanced completion like selector completion, validation, hyperlink you can activate [the advanced support for jQuery](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-Extension-support).

It works too with HTML/JSP. Here a screenshot with your JSP sample:

[image]

Comment: I have tried that but it is very slow. Every CTRL+space it seems to call to some remote server and autocomplete is not show up.

Answer (score 0):

After you install JSDT jQuery and add jQuery library, in the same window, you have to set Source, like below

[image: add *.js *.html]

Then it does work in your js and html files, good luck!